# IBM Plex .woff/.woff2 fonts not displaying properly with mix up of uppercase and lowercase

Tags: webfonts

[image: screenshot of webpage]

Headings are using different font-family to the content, and headings are displaying properly. The content should be IBM Plex with both .woff and .woff2 formats available but it looks very buggy with a strange mix of capitals, and lower-case in capitals.

If it was due to slow internet connection shouldn't it display the default 'Times New Roman'? And why the random capital letters?

I tried different browsers, I only saw this issue on a Windows machine (Chrome), the same webpage loads fine on a Mac.